# Python command line not accepting tabs

Tags: python, windows

(I don't know if this is an appropriate question for StackOverflow, as it's about a tool rather than a language.)

My Python 3.3.1 (32-bit) command line ("C:\Python33\python.exe") has stopped accepting tab characters. It can print them, but pressing the Tab key just makes the cursor blink at me (it reacts, but doesn't move). It wasn't happening earlier today.

I also have 2.7 (32-bit) and 3.2 (64-bit) installed, and neither of them have this problem. Trying to run each of the python.exe executables from the same cmd.exe window gives the same result, so it's not due to the command line window settings. Running a .py file (">python my.py") doesn't have the problem. IDLE for 3.3 doesn't have the problem.

Also, when pasting text from the clipboard, they're read s l o w l y (takes about 15 seconds to read a hundred lines of 50-char commented lines, compared to less than a second on the others) and

The only change I remember making recently (since the last time I remember opening python.exe) was to install Scipy for 3.3 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack (32-bit).

No, I have not tried turning the computer off and on again. I hope not to. I haven't tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.3, since that means reinstalling packages. Updating to 3.3.3 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me.  What do you mean your ptyhon interpreter has stopped accepting tab characters?  Do you mean from within an interactive session? Do you mean passing tab characters as part of input arguments?

Comment: At the >>> prompt (running python.exe with no arguments), pressing the tab key does nothing, and pasted tabs are ignored.

Comment: What do you want the tab to do when you press the tab key?  If you want it to do autocomplete you'll have to install something like ipython.  If you want a string to have a tab character you need to specify it with s1 = 'abc\tthat is a tab'

Comment: @cgohlke: That worked. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? I'll try to figure out why it worked later.

Comment: @Paul: I use tabs to indent. The tab character is being read and discarded. Pasting code into the >>> prompt strips the tabs, which means I can't define functions with tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the `pyreadline` directory in `lib\site-packages`. [Scipy-stack](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack) includes [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline), which is required for the IPython terminal but also changes the behavior of the standard interactive prompt.

Comment: Nice call Christoph, on a side note, your packages have been very helpful on my windows x64 bit work in the last several years.